# SQL SERVER+ ANDROID STUDIO KOTLIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, android-studio, kotlin

Como puedo validar si no se encuentra en la base de datos que no pueda logearse, o si no coinciden los parametros, adjunto codigo
Adjunto tambien base de datos me logea super bien pero es con cualquier parametro que coloco no solamente las credenciales reales, estaba probando y dejando sin nada solamente los campos vacios me deriva igualmente al mensaje usuario logeado

```
 class MainLogin : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.login)

    val btninicio: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnInicio)
    btninicio.setOnClickListener {
        var conn: Connection?= null

        var v_usuario1: EditText = findViewById(R.id.usuario_b)
        val user1 = v_usuario1.text.toString()

        var v_contrasena1: EditText = findViewById(R.id.contrasena_b)
        val pass1 = v_contrasena1.text.toString()
        try {
            val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
            //--- Coneccion a la Base de Datos

            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()
            //--- Coneccion a SQLSERVER Local  -----

            val dbURL =
                "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.21:1433;databasename=DB_Android;user=Matias;password=Ma2010aS"

            val conn: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL)

            if (conn == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coneccion NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            } else {

                // --- Realizamos la consulta a la tabla¡´`
                val Consulta =
                    "SELECT nombre_usuario,contrasena FROM usuario where nombre_usuario='" + user1 + "'and contrasena='" + pass1 + "'"

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sqlstatement, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                val stm: Statement = conn.createStatement()
                val rs: ResultSet = stm.executeQuery(Consulta)
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Usuario Logeado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }


    }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que siempre que existe una conexión válida, estas imprimiento el mensaje, pero esto puede no ser verdad. Debes revisar si la consulta obtuvo un resultado y con base en esto mostrar el mensaje para indicar si se conectó o no.

```
if (conn == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coneccion NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            } else {

                // --- Realizamos la consulta a la tabla¡´`
                val Consulta =
                    "SELECT nombre_usuario,contrasena FROM usuario where nombre_usuario='" + user1 + "'and contrasena='" + pass1 + "'"

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sqlstatement, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                val stm: Statement = conn.createStatement()
                val rs: ResultSet = stm.executeQuery(Consulta)

               if (!rs.next()) { //*no existe resultado
                  //*No se conecta.
               } else {
                  Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Usuario Logeado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()                    
               }
                
            }
```